# Something has gone wrong and this URL cannot be processed at this time + Zoo Visitor

Tags: zoo-visitor, registration

I upgraded ExpressionEngine version to 2.9.0. and also Zoo Visitor to latest version. After upgrade, I am seeing a very strange error message after submitting Zoo Registration form `exp:zoo_visitor:registration_form`

> **Error**
>
> Something has gone wrong and this URL cannot be processed at this
>   time.

Before, upgrade everything was working fine. Could anyone please help me.

Answer (score 4):

Probably you have some broken conditional tag. The conditionals are more strict since 2.9.

Comment: not sure if so as after submitting the Zoo Registration form, the member get created but this error is showing.

Comment: Not even on the template loaded after the registration?

Comment: Robson, you are true the conditionals are more strict since 2.9. EE 2.8 didn't show a message error with this conditional code: {if segment_2 = ''} .... {/if}. It was working and without error message with only one = sign. EE 2.9 didn't accept this error !!

Comment: For me, EE 2.8 didn't show an error message for an (inadvertently) unclosed `{if}` conditional, but 2.9 did. Basically, I had: `{exp:channel:entries} {matrix_field} {if matrix_col} {/matrix_field} {/exp:channel:entries}`. Perhaps I didn't get error messages in 2.8 because the conditional was within the matrix tags...?

Answer (score 0):

This could be caused by missing curly bracket.

I had hard time debugging this, turned out I had

> return="{segment_1}/{segment_2/thanks"

where I should had

> return="{segment_1}/{segment_2}/thanks"